# I can't get slot templates to work with vue-multiselect 3.0.0 beta 1

Tags: vuejs3, vue-multiselect

I have tried the sample in the doc and tried updating to use Vue 3 slot options and it still doesn't work. Has anyone gotten this to work.

Using the way the docs show it. https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-custom-option-template
https://jsfiddle.net/c2e968g5

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-multiselect@3.0.0-beta.1/dist/vue-multiselect.esm.css" asp-append-version="true" />
<style>
    /* Used to hide VueJS templates */
    [v-cloak] {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "vue": "https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.45/dist/vue.esm-browser.prod.js",
        "vue_multiselect": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-multiselect@3.0.0-beta.1/dist/vue-multiselect.esm.min.js"
      }
    }
</script>
<script type="module">
    import { createApp } from 'vue'
    import VueMultiselect from "vue_multiselect";

    const app = createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                value: null,
                options: [{ name: "John", last: "Smith" }, { name: "Bob", last: "Chair" }, {name:"Chuck",last:"Norris"}]
            }
        },
        components: {
            vuemultiselect: VueMultiselect
        }
    }).mount('#app');
</script>
<div id="app" v-cloak>
    <vuemultiselect
                    v-model="value"
                    placeholder="Start typing to find address"
                    open-direction="bottom"
                    :options="options"
                    :options-limit="100"
                    :limit="20"
                    :searchable="true"
                    :hide-selected="false"
                    :close-on-select="true"
                    :clear-on-select="false"
                    :multiple="false"
                    :internal-search="true"
                    :max-height="300"
                    :show-no-results="false"
                    :preserve-search="false"
                    :allow-empty="true"
                    :reset-after="false">
        <template slot="singleLabel" slot-scope="props">
            <span>{{props.option.name}}</span>
        </template>
        <template slot="option" slot-scope="props">
            <b>{{props.option.name}}</b>
            <br />
            <span>{{props.option.last}}</span>
        </template>
    </vuemultiselect>
</div>
```

Using new Vue 3 slot options
https://jsfiddle.net/c2e968g5/1/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-multiselect@3.0.0-beta.1/dist/vue-multiselect.esm.css" asp-append-version="true" />
<style>
    /* Used to hide VueJS templates */
    [v-cloak] {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "vue": "https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.45/dist/vue.esm-browser.prod.js",
        "vue_multiselect": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-multiselect@3.0.0-beta.1/dist/vue-multiselect.esm.min.js"
      }
    }
</script>
<script type="module">
    import { createApp } from 'vue'
    import VueMultiselect from "vue_multiselect";

    const app = createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                value: null,
                options: [{ name: "John", last: "Smith" }, { name: "Bob", last: "Chair" }, {name:"Chuck",last:"Norris"}]
            }
        },
        components: {
            vuemultiselect: VueMultiselect
        }
    }).mount('#app');
</script>
<div id="app" v-cloak>
    <vuemultiselect
                    v-model="value"
                    placeholder="Start typing to find address"
                    open-direction="bottom"
                    :options="options"
                    :options-limit="100"
                    :limit="20"
                    :searchable="true"
                    :hide-selected="false"
                    :close-on-select="true"
                    :clear-on-select="false"
                    :multiple="false"
                    :internal-search="true"
                    :max-height="300"
                    :show-no-results="false"
                    :preserve-search="false"
                    :allow-empty="true"
                    :reset-after="false">
        <template slot="singleLabel"  v-slot="{ name }">
            <span>{{name}}</span>
        </template>
        <template slot="option" v-slot="{ name, last }">
            <b>{{name}}</b>
            <br />
            <span>{{last}}</span>
        </template>
    </vuemultiselect>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to write it is:

```html
<template v-slot:option="{ option }">
  <b>{{ option.name }}</b>
</template>
```

or shorthand:

```html
<template #option="{ option }">
  <b>{{ option.name }}</b>
</template>
```

So there is no `slot` property anymore, and the slot name goes after the `v-slot:` (or the shorthand `#`), slot props follow the statement immediately:

```
v-slot:option="{ option, search, index }"
```

---

The problem with the `singleLabel` slot is particular to your setup, where you are using the multiselect in HTML directly, and not in a component, which means that the browser sees it before Vue does and performs changes to it.

So from a statement like

```html
<template v-slot:singleLabel="{ option }">
```

the camelCased `singleLabel` is turned into lowercase `singlelabel`:

```html
<template v-slot:singlelabel="{ option }">
```

But that slot indeed does not exist.

The problem does not occur if you put the vuemultiselect in a component, see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/orysdcxw/).

If that is not an option, as a hack, you could use a dynamic slot:

```html
<template v-slot:[slotname]="{ option }">
```

where `slotname` (again, lowercase) is a variable containing the slot name as a string, i.e. `"singleLabel"`.

Comment: This worked for the option slot but I can't seem to get this to work for singleLabel. 
```
<template v-slot:singleLabel="{ option }">
                                    <span>{{option.name}}</span>
                                </template>
```

Comment: This happens because you are using the slot in the HTML and not a component. Have a look at the updated answer

Comment: Is that a Vue thing or a vue-multiselect issue? Wonder why it matters how it gets used. I would think everything would need to get rendered first before displaying.

Comment: Yes, it is a weird technical limitation. Templates in components are pre-compiled by Vue, so it can do all sorts of things with it, like resolving PascalCased component tag names, but code in the main page is not seen as HTML by Vue, but as DOM elements. Information not present in the nodes is lost. Nothing that Vue can do about it. You don't run into the issue very often, but when you do, it almost always costs you an hour or so. In this case, Vue-multiselect could have avoided the issue by declaring the slot names in kebab-case, but what can you do...